# Android ViewPager как пролистывать напопловину?

Tags: android-viewpager, android, java

Есть два фрагмента и перелистывающий их `ViewPager`, мне нужно, чтобы первый фрагмент занимал по ширине не весь `ViewPager`, а его часть, т.е. чтобы был полностью виден первый фрагмент и левая часть второго фрагмента.

Возможно такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewpager.setClipToPadding(false)
viewpager.setPadding(left,0,right,0)
```

Где left и right - ширина "куска" левого и правого фрагментов, которые будут показываться одновременно с основным.
Если нужно добавить также и отступ между фрагментами:

```
viewpager.setPageMargin(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, не очень точно вопрос задал. Нужно было, чтобы только первый фрагмент был узкий, а остальные нормальные по ширине.

Я в `PageAdapter'е` переопределил метод `getPageWidth`

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return (position==0)?0.5f:1.0f;
}
```

Получилось то, что нужно.